# How to correct the image path on another drive for an image in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that I want to display inside the `div` tag as a background image in the file path stored in the `imageUrl` variable.
But the problem is that it can not display the image from this file path.
While there is an image with this name on drive `D:\`.
I do not know how I can solve this problem, please help us
Thanks

```
  function App() {
      const imageUrl = "D:/image.jpg"
    
      const style = {
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px",
        background: `url(${imageUrl}) no-repeat`,
        backgroundSize: "500px 500px",
        border: "solid red",
        borderRadius: "5px",
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
            <div style={style}></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: the file needs to be inside the projects directory path or needs to be hosted. You can import the file like a normal file and can use it

Comment: @innocent My file is in another drive. For this case, how can I import and use the file?